# How to create components in npm package for angular projects

Tags: javascript, angular

I have multi angular projects and i will use the multi-components that I created to use in other my projects.
My projects is:

```
 + shop
   - src
     - app
     - components
   - e2e
   - angular.json
   - package.json
   - tsconfig.json

 + site
    - src
      - app
      - components
    - e2e
    - angular.json
    - package.json
    - tsconfig.json

    ....
```

I will create multi-component in npm for use in all my projects.
How i create npm package?

Answer (score 4):

you could create a library with

```
ng generate library my-library
```

and move your components to `projects/my-library`.

To build it, you can run

```
ng build my-library
```

The result of the build will be a publishable npm package. To publish it, run

```
cd dist/my-library
npm publish
```

see https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries and https://angular.io/cli/generate#library

Answer (score 1):

Find it.
Use from `Verdaccio` package.